# Determine if Current time falls within time ranges.. If not find what the next open window is

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an application where I need to send messages to businesses only if they are within their set message windows.

a business might have a set of windows mon-fri  10am-3pm,  6pm-11pm
                                       sat-sun  2am-6am,  3pm-4pm

This is a sample

So a business could have multiple business windows per day and they could vary by day of the week.  Each business would also be in a different timezone so that also has to be taken into account.

When a message comes in for delivery I need to know if the current time is within a window.  If it is not, it will be queued and I need to deliver it on the next open window.

I am kinda at a loss on where and how to start on this one.  Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if the question was not granular enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question is too broad and is unlikely to get a response.

Comment: I'm perplexed by the downvote as it seems to be a clear and interesting question. This is a good example of the problem that arises when downvoters fail to leave a comment that explains why they fault the question. Here the OP probably has no idea of the reason for the downvote and therefore doesn't know how to repair the question to the downvoter's satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you were to construct a hash whose keys are businesses and whose values are windows, the windows being an array of seven arrays, one for each day of the week:

```
windows = [sun_windows, mon_windows, ... , sat_windows]
```

Each daily window is an array of ranges of the form `first_sec..last_sec`, `first_sec` and `last_sec` being seconds from midnight. These ranges are ordered in the sense that end of each range (seconds) is less than the beginning the next range.

Suppose, for example, that for a particular business there were two windows on Mondays, `8:00-12:00` and `13:00-17:00`. Then

```
mon_windows = [8*3600..12*3600, 13*3600..17*3600]
  #=> [28800..43200, 46800..61200]
```

Suppose now one wanted to know if `[:mon, 44000]` were currently within a window for this business. We could use the following method for that task.

```
def covered?(windows_today, secs)
  windows_today.each do |r|
    return [false, r] if r.begin > secs
    return true if r.cover?(secs)
  end
  false
end
```

As Monday is the second day of the week (offset 1), we would execute:

```
covered?(windows[1], 44000)
  #=> [false, 46800..61200]
```

where:

```
windows_today = windows[1]
  #=> [28800..43200, 46800..61200]
```

There are three possible return values from this method.

- `true`: the message can be delivered immediately;
- `[false, r]`: the message cannot be delivered immediately but can be delivered during the (next) window (range) `r` the same day; and
- `false`: the message cannot be delivered the same day.

Depending on requirements, possibly only `r.begin` (`46800` in the example) need be returned in the second case.

In the example, `44000` is not within a window on Monday and the next window is the range `46800..61200` the same day.

We would be finished unless `false` were returned. If that case we would need to determine the next window.

```
def next_window(windows, start_day)
  dow = 7.times.find { |i| windows[(start_day + i) % 7].any? }
  dow = (start_day + dow) % 7 
  [dow, windows[dow].first]
end
```

where `start_day` equals the `1` plus current day-of-week number (e.g., `1` for Monday, making `start_day = 2`).

Notice that if the business is only open on Monday `windows[start_day+i) % 7] #=> []` for `i = 0..5` (so `windows[start_day+i) % 7].first #=> nil`), and the method would return

```
next_window(windows, 2)
  #[1, 28800..43200]
```

`28800..43200` being the first window the following Monday.

Regarding time zones it would seem simplest to make all times Grenwich Mean Times.